# In a nonabelian finite group $G$, if a prime $p$ divides order of $|G|$, $p$ divides order of centralizer of some element which is not in the center

Tags: group-theory

Here's what I want to prove:

Suppose $G$ be nonabelian finite group and $p$ be a prime which divides the order of G. Then there is some element $b\in G$ such that $b \not\in Z(G)$ and $p$ divides $|Z(b)|$. (Note: $Z(b)$ is the centralizer of $b$)

Here's my attempt:
Suppose that for all $b \not\in Z(G)$, $p$ does not divide $|Z(b)|$. Let $\{a_1 , \ldots , a_k \}$ be the system of representatives of those conjugacy classes which contain more than one element. Then $a_i \not\in Z(G)$ and  since $p$ does not divide $|Z(a_i)|$, $p$ must divide $[G: Z(a_i)]$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots , k\}$. Then by the class equation, $p$ must divide $|Z(G)|$.

This is where I am stuck. I cannot decide what to do after this. Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have already proved that $p$ divides the order of the center. Now if you take any element outside the center , its centralizer contains the center and so by Lagrange, the order of the centralizer is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy. I was thinking too hard, I guess.